# How to use grep to match lines where the first character falls in a range?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, regex

I am trying to grep lines where the first character is an A, B, or C.

I am trying this:

`grep -i "^[a-c]*" data.txt`

I want it to only care about the very first character, the rest of the line I don't care about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you have used the `*` (zero or more) quantifier, your expression is going to match every line. Change it to

```
grep -i "^[a-c]" data.txt
```

and it should work as you intend.

Comment: @ArukaJ https://askubuntu.com/questions/714503/regular-expressions-vs-filename-globbing